# O Android é um SO ou um software stack?

Tags: android

As definições dadas [pelo Google](http://source.android.com/) para o Android

> "Android is an open-source software stack for a wide range of mobile
>   devices and a corresponding open-source project led by Google."

e [pela Wikipedia americana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)

> "Android is an operating system based on the Linux kernel with a user
>   interface based on direct manipulation, designed primarily for
>   touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablet
>   computers[...]"

me deixaram na dúvida sobre os objetivos da plataforma.

Talvez uma resposta que venha a explicar a diferença entre SO e software stack venha trazer ao leitor o entendimento sobre esses dois conceitos.

Comment: Acho que [um determinado trecho do wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Software_stack) responde a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O sistema operacional é o núcleo central do sistema e o *Software Stack* é o software situado acima do kernel que aprimora e amplia a funcionalidade do sistema.

No Linux, o kernel é o sistema operacional. O *Software Stack* pode incluir coisas como:

- O sistema de janelas X.
- O gerenciador de janelas *Gnome*.
- Aplicações para o gerenciamento do sistema.

Então, coisas como um aplicativo de painel de controle para editar as configurações do sistema não fazem parte do sistema operacional. Eles fazem parte do *Software Stack* em cima do sistema operacional.

Veja o gráfico a seguir para um melhor entendimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Windows tende a borrar a linha um pouco, mas o Linux faz com que seja um pouco mais visível. No Windows aplicações que se encaixam nesse escopo são por exemplo o *Windows Server, Internet Explorer, .NET, SQL Server*.

Referências:

1. [Android software stack](http://mahalelabs.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/android-software-stack/)
2. [What is difference between Software Stack and OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283725/what-is-difference-between-software-stack-and-os-why-android-is-not-an-os-but)
3. [Software Stack](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/27268/software-stack)

Comment: Posso dizer que as camadas acima do kernel: hardware, libraries, Android Runtime, Application Framework e Applications formam o software stack do Android?

Comment: Correções: o kernel **É** o núcleo. São sinônimos. _"The OS is the core kernel of the system"_ deveria ser traduzido como _"O sistema operacional é o núcleo central do sistema"_. E kernel é diferente de sistema operacional. Por exemplo, https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.html (tradução do texto de Richard Stallman) faz uma comparação entre os dois.

Comment: Acho que o @GeisonSantos se refere à camada _Hardware Abstraction Layer_. Essa também forma, não?

Comment: Exatamente @Piovezan. Falha minha não ter colocado o nome por extenso.

Comment: @Piovezan Você está correto, o *HAL* também faz parte desse escopo, como citado pela Wikipedia [aqui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_(software)).

Comment: @Sunstreaker sua resposta foi muito boa, mas eu acho que muita coisa dos comentários poderiam ser incluídos nela, inclusive a própria resposta **em texto** dizendo que o Android é um SS. Você mostrou isso através da imagem, mas acho que seria legal responder com palavras. Só uma sugestão.